# Pingfederate opentoken module CORS request returns 302 instead of 200

Tags: javascript, cors, iis-7.5, pingfederate, preflight

We are using Ping Federate to protect two web servers (both IIS and both protected using the IIS integration kit, or opentoken module from Ping). One server hosts a WEB API application and the other hosts a webpage. The Web API application has CORS enabled.

The webpage makes Ajax post requests with json data to the API server. This causes the browser to initiate a preflight options request. On the API server, the Ping module intercepts this request that does not contain credentials (the specs say that preflight options requests are not supposed to contain credentials) and returns a 302 redirect before the Web API code can handle it when it should return a 200.

My only current guess is to make a custom module that handles options requests and install it ahead of the opentoken module. Are there any other possible/better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for PING I've put an IAuthorizationFilter on top of their .NET Integration Kit/Agent. The nice thing about a custom filter like this is you gain a lot more control over the security requirements of your API endpoints.

When writing the filter I used the following references:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx

  using opentoken;
  using PF.SAML.Result;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Configuration;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Net.Http;
  using System.Net.Http.Headers;
  using System.Security.Claims;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Web.Http.Filters;

  namespace PF.SAML.Filters
  {
      public class PingAuthenticationAttribute : IAuthenticationFilter
      {
          public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }

  ```
      // http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters
      // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx
      public async Task AuthenticateAsync( HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
      {
          await Task.Run( () => {
              /*
               * Look for credentials in the request.
               * If there are no credentials, do nothing and return (no-op).
               * If there are credentials but the filter does not recognize the authentication scheme, do nothing and return (no-op). Another filter in the pipeline might understand the scheme.
               * If there are credentials that the filter understands, try to authenticate them.
               * If the credentials are bad, return 401 by setting context.ErrorResult.
               * If the credentials are valid, create an IPrincipal and set context.Principal.
               */
              var opentoken = context.Request.Headers.GetCookies()
                  .SelectMany( c => c.Cookies )
                  .Where( c => c.Name == "opentoken" )
                  .FirstOrDefault();

              if( opentoken == null ) return;

              var userInfo = getOpenToken( opentoken.Value );

              if( userInfo == null ) {
                  context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult( "Invalid Token", context.Request );
                  return;
              }

              var claims = new List<Claim>();
              foreach( var item in userInfo ) {
                  foreach( var value in userInfo[item.Key] ) {
                      claims.Add( new Claim( item.Key, value ) );
                  }
              }

              var id = new ClaimsIdentity( claims, "opentoken" );
              var principle = new ClaimsPrincipal( new[] { id } );

              context.Principal = principle;

          } );
      }

      public async Task ChallengeAsync( HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
      {
          await Task.Run( () => {
              var challenge = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "SAML" );
              context.Result = new AddChallengeOnUnauthorizedResult( challenge, context.Result );
          } );
      }


      private MultiStringDictionary getOpenToken( string token )
      {
          MultiStringDictionary attributes = null;

          Configuration.Agent agentConfig = (Configuration.Agent) ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "pfConfigurationGroup/agentConfiguration" ); 
          AgentConfiguration config = new AgentConfiguration
          {
              CookieDomain = agentConfig.CookieDomain,
              CookiePath = agentConfig.CookiePath,
              NotBeforeTolerance = agentConfig.NotBeforeTolerance,
              ObfuscatePassword = agentConfig.ObfuscatePassword,
              RenewUntilLifetime = agentConfig.RenewUntilLifetime,
              SecureCookie = agentConfig.SecureCookie,
              SessionCookie = agentConfig.SessionCookie,
              TokenLifetime = agentConfig.TokenLifetime,
              TokenName = agentConfig.TokenName,
              UseCookie = agentConfig.UseCookie,
              UseSunJCE = agentConfig.UseSunJCE,
              UseVerboseErrorMessages = agentConfig.UseVerboseErrorMessages
          };

          var str = ( config.ObfuscatePassword
              ? Encoding.UTF8.GetString( Obfuscator.Deobfuscate( agentConfig.Password ) )
              : Encoding.ASCII.GetString( Convert.FromBase64String( agentConfig.Password ) ) );
          config.SetPassword( str, Token.CipherSuite.AES_128_CBC );

          // TODO: Check for token expiration

          Agent agent = new Agent( config );
          attributes = agent.ReadTokenMultiStringDictionary( token );

          return attributes;
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: I ended up combining my servers to work around this issue. This does seem like the best way if PING doesn't provide a solution so I will mark this as an answer but might change it if PING provides useful info.

Comment: I would recommend putting an example of the filter you created (if possible) or a more general filter example. StackOverflow frowns upon just link answers (links could die, harder to find info, etc). - An example gets an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a bug with the PING Federate IIS Agent/integration kit implementation?

I agree with the OP. The current W3C recommendation (https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request) explicitly says to **exclude** user credentials in the preflight/OPTIONS request. An OPTIONS request should therefore allow an anonymous request. Getting a 302 pointing back to the Identity Provider (IdP) says to me it is not following the recommendation.

---

(This only helps on the PING server itself, the integration kit still needs to allow anonymous OPTIONS requests.)
Ping Federate came back with more configuration settings in the jetty config file:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE OPTIONS HEAD</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method> 
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: I think it may be bug. I'm waiting to hear back from PING to see if they have any more info about this problem.